Как вывести значение переменной в HTML?
Есть функция, переменная которой принимает значение ID из текущего значения  в поле .


<select id="crs">
  <option value="2">Audi</option>
  <option value="1">Volkswagen</option>
</select>
<script>
  function getValue() {
    var select = document.getElementById("crs");
    var value = select.value;
  }
</script>



Как сделать чтобы значение этой переменной выводилось в HTML например по такому принципу?
<div id="val"></div>

document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = 'value';



Как сделать чтобы значение этой переменной выводилось в HTML например по такому принципу?

Например вот так...


test.call(crs)
crs.addEventListener('change', test)
//
function test() {
    val.textContent = this.value;
}
<select id="crs">
  <option value="2">Audi</option>
  <option value="1">Volkswagen</option>
</select>
<div id="val"></div>



